# Can not find symbol varaible i

Tags: arrays, string, variables

I am writing a program which counts how many times each of the alphabetic characters (convert lower case to upper case) appears in the data file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class CharDistribution{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
  File file = new File (args[0]);


  String[] letters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
  int numbers[] = new int [26];

  Scanner input=new Scanner(file);
  input.useDelimiter("");

  while (input.hasNext()){
     String nextLetter = input.next().toUpperCase( );

     for (int i = 0; i <letters.length; i++);
     {
        String letter = letters[i].toUpperCase( );

        if (letters.equals(nextLetter)){
           numbers[i] = numbers[i] + 1;
        }

     }

     for (int i = 0; i <letters.length; i++);
     {
        System.out.println(letters[i].toUpperCase( ) + " - " + numbers[i]);

     }
  }
  }
  }
```

For some reason, the program is unable to find the variable i which I used in the for loop.

All 5 times I used i after the loop are giving me this error "cannot find symbol". Ive looked over it a dozen times and cant seem to find what is wrong with the code. Do you see an issue I might have over looked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the `for` which terminates it, making the following block unrelated to it, and thus unable to resolve `i`. Just remove it, and you should be fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i <letters.length; i++) // ; removed here
{
```

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that, so foolish of me. thank you.